# ESP01 doesn't show any network

Tags: esp8266, wifi, esp01

I send the `AT-CWLAP` command to my ESP01 module, but it returns the same command without any network detected.

First I set the module to mode 1 (client mode) with `AT+CWMODE=1`, then I enter the command `AT+RST`, and finally `AT+CWLAP`.

I'm using a Nucleo board to communicate with it. Because of power issues I decided to use an external power supply, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have the gnd/0V connected between the two boards?

Comment: Yes, I do. I put a capacitor between gnd and 3.3v and now it works.

Comment: Please formally answer your own question @Andrea so that others can learn from your mistake in the future.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok, I'll do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. The problem was related to a poor stability of the power supply, to solve it I added a 220uF capacitor between Vcc and GND. Since in the communication manager I created I set a timer that stops the communication between my board and the chip if it lasts too long, I also incremented that timer for operation that requires wifi.